# How to return max value with grouping in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 1 table with 3 columns and many more rows of data shown than this:

```
ID  CD     TS
----------------------
1    A  2/28/2014 10:14
1    B  3/25/2014 13:21
2    C  3/3/2014 10:15
2    D  3/3/2014 13:48
```

I'm looking for anything that will return the CD value for the max(TS), grouped by ID. The results will look like this:

```
ID  CD
----------
1   B
2   D
n…  n…
```

I've been racking my brain and googling, but cannot seem to make subselects, self joins, or analytics work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try googling for "analytic queries" and the ROW_NUMBER() function. This will help do what you want. Calculate ROW_NUMBER within a partition by CD, ordered by timestamp DESC, and then select the record s with a ROW_NUMBER() of 1

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work.  There may be a simpler solution w/o analytic function, but I am tired and its Friday.

```
SELECT id, cd
FROM
(
   SELECT id, cd ,
   row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY ts DESC) rn
   FROM test
 )
WHERE rn = 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9304fc/6)

Answer (score 0):

Some other variations:

```
SELECT id, CD
  FROM my_table a
  WHERE ts = (SELECT MAX(ts)
                FROM my_table b
                WHERE b.id = a.id
                GROUP BY id)
```

Another:

```
WITH oldest AS (
  SELECT id, MAX(ts) AS ts
    FROM my_table b
    GROUP BY id)
SELECT id, CD
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN oldest b ON (a.id = b.id AND a.ts = b.ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has the very hande [KEEP](http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2012/09/keep-clause.html) clause for that :)

```
select id
,      max(cd) keep (dense_rank last order by ts) cd
from   my_table
group by id
```